# How do you access Google service using a java client?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, oauth, google-sheets

I am developing a java application which is **registered** on Google Apps Engine (GAE) with the name "searcegadget2". I have implemented **3-legged OAuth** with OAuthHmacSha1Signer(). I am getting the Access Token **properly** & storing it on **Session** (session is *enabled*).

Next, I am calling the servlet using a link onclick event. This servlet is to access the Spreadsheet service using the accesstoken. My code is :

```
            GoogleOAuthParameters oauthParameters = new GoogleOAuthParameters();
            oauthParameters.setOAuthConsumerKey(CONSUMER_KEY);
            oauthParameters.setOAuthConsumerSecret(CONSUMER_SECRET);
            oauthParameters.setOAuthType(OAuthParameters.OAuthType.THREE_LEGGED_OAUTH);
            oauthParameters.setScope("https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/");
            oauthParameters.setOAuthToken(request.getSession().getAttribute("oauth_token").toString());
            oauthParameters.setOAuthVerifier(request.getSession().getAttribute("oauth_verifier").toString());
            oauthParameters.setOAuthTokenSecret(request.getSession().getAttribute("oauth_token_secret").toString());



            out.println("Accessing Service");
            GoogleService googleService = new GoogleService("wise", "searceapps-searcegadget2-1");
            out.println("<br/>Setting Parameter");
            googleService.setOAuthCredentials(oauthParameters, new OAuthHmacSha1Signer());
            out.println("<br/>Setting URl");
            URL feedUrl = new URL("https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/spreadsheets/private/full");
            out.println("<br/>Accessing ResultFeed");
            SpreadsheetFeed resultFeed = googleService.getFeed(feedUrl, SpreadsheetFeed.class);

            out.println("<div id='feed'>");
            out.println("Response Data:");
            out.println("=====================================================");
            out.println("| TITLE: " + resultFeed.getTitle().getPlainText());
            if (resultFeed.getEntries().isEmpty()) {
                out.println("|\tNo entries found.");
            } else {
                List<SpreadsheetEntry> spreadsheets = resultFeed.getEntries();
                for (int i = 0; i < spreadsheets.size(); i++) {
                    SpreadsheetEntry entry = spreadsheets.get(i);
                    System.out.println("\t" + entry.getTitle().getPlainText());
                }
            }
            out.println("=====================================================");
            out.println("</div>");
```

I have printed all the oauthParameter for testing & they are properly set. But, while calling this servlet, the only output that I am getting is :

> Accessing Service

I have added, gdata-spreadsheet-3.0.jar but still it is not even allowing me **to create** the service object !!! What is the problem ?

Also, as per it given [here](http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/javadoc/com/google/gdata/client/spreadsheet/SpreadsheetService.html), "Application names should preferably have the format [company-id]-[app-name]-[app-version]. The name will be used by the Google servers to monitor the source of authentication." I don't know where I find my company id, but my app name is "searcegadget2" & version is "1".

For reference : [Google Spreadsheets API Developer's Guide: Java](http://code.google.com/apis/spreadsheets/data/2.0/developers_guide_java.html), [Using the Java Client Library](http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/client-java.html), [OAuth in the Google Data Protocol Client Libraries](http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/docs/auth/oauth.html)

Comment: I'm guessing you have a try/catch around this code that catches and discards all exceptions? That's the only reason I can think of why this would abort halfway through with no exception.

Comment: You may want to switch to using the new Google API Java Client (http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/) which is a newer, actively developed successor to the GData Java library. http://code.google.com/p/gdata-java-client/wiki/MigratingToGoogleApiJavaClient

Comment: "of course it is" what? You should never use generic exception handlers and just discard the exception!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found,

Google Service has dependency on : [guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/downloads/detail?name=guava-r08.zip&can=2&q=) as it is mentioned [here](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-java-client/issues/detail?id=180).

Answer (score -1):

here is an [example](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-java-client/source/browse/trunk/java/sample/oauth/OAuthExample.java) that should help you.

I think you forgot to add some parameters like the scope.