# 'AuthSub token has wrong scope' when trying to retrieve google spreadsheet

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, gdata, google-sheets

My code is: (sensitive info removed)

```
SpreadsheetService service = new SpreadsheetService("MySpreadsheetIntegration-v1");
// service.setUserCredentials(<email>, <pw>);

GoogleOAuthParameters oauthParameters = new GoogleOAuthParameters();
oauthParameters.setOAuthConsumerKey("xxx.yyy.no");
oauthParameters.setOAuthConsumerSecret("XXX");
oauthParameters.setOAuthToken("YYYY");
oauthParameters.setOAuthTokenSecret("ZZZZ");
oauthParameters.setScope("https://docs.google.com/feeds/ https://docs.googleusercontent.com/ https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/");

service.setOAuthCredentials(oauthParameters, new OAuthHmacSha1Signer());

// Define the URL to request. This should never change.
URL SPREADSHEET_FEED_URL = new URL("https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/spreadsheets/private/full");

// Make a request to the API and get all spreadsheets.
SpreadsheetFeed feed = service.getFeed(SPREADSHEET_FEED_URL, SpreadsheetFeed.class);
List<SpreadsheetEntry> spreadsheets = feed.getEntries();

// Iterate through all of the spreadsheets returned
for (SpreadsheetEntry spreadsheet : spreadsheets) {
// Print the title of this spreadsheet to the screen
System.out.println(spreadsheet.getTitle().getPlainText());
}
```

Issue:

```
WARNING: Authentication error: Unable to respond to any of these challenges: {authsub=WWW-Authenticate: AuthSub realm="https://www.google.com/accounts//AuthSubRequest"}
```

and

```
com.google.gdata.util.AuthenticationException: Token invalid - AuthSub token has wrong scope
```

I tried clientLogin method (setUserCredentials(, )) and that works fine.
I also know my OAuthConsumerKey, OAuthConsumerSecret, OAuthToken and OAuthTokenSecret work, cos I access a different feed using them (picasa)
I have tried setting different combinations of the above 3 scopes, but no luck.
I have seen [this](http://www.geoffmcqueen.com/2010/03/14/token-invalid-authsub-token-has-wrong-scope-oauth-google-problem/) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4883123/how-do-you-access-google-service-using-a-java-client/4885506#4885506), but again, no luck.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32121847/java-google-sheets-api-authsub-token-has-wrong-scope/32127719#32127719).

Try to delete the following directory:

```
$HOME/.credentials
```

After what run the program again, it's gonna make a callback and ask you to grant permissions for your application in Google Console and now it's gonna work properly.