# Java, Google Sheets API: AuthSub token has wrong scope

Tags: java, google-drive-api, google-sheets

I was following documentation on Google Sheets API, but I can't make it work. When I'm trying to access a spreadsheets I got following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.google.gdata.client.GoogleService$SessionExpiredException: Token invalid - AuthSub token has wrong scope
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Token invalid - AuthSub token has wrong scope</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000">
<H1>Token invalid - AuthSub token has wrong scope</H1>
<H2>Error 401</H2>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

with code:

```
SpreadsheetService sheetService = new SpreadsheetService("App-v1");

sheetService.setProtocolVersion(SpreadsheetService.Versions.V3);
sheetService.setOAuth2Credentials(DriveService.getCredential());

URL mFeedURL = new URL(SPREADSHEET_FEED);
SpreadsheetFeed feed = sheetService.getFeed(mFeedURL, SpreadsheetFeed.class);
```

but when I'm retrieving file names from Google Drive it all goes well.

---

The scopes and feed urls that I'm using:

```
SPREADSHEET_FEED = "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/spreadsheets/private/full"

SCOPES = Arrays.asList(DriveScopes.DRIVE_METADATA_READONLY,
                       "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/"
                      );
```

Is that something with permissions or token or it's just the wrong implementation?

Comment: As per this [page](http://geoffmcqueen.com/2010/03/14/token-invalid-authsub-token-has-wrong-scope-oauth-google-problem/), it is a generic error message, and applies to any case where the scope of access doesn’t match what you’re asking for, whether it is OAuth or AuthSub. So the reason could be because of using a scope which is deprecated.  The "https://docs.google.com/feeds/" is for Docs list API and was deprecated on April 20, 2015. Check this [page](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/migration) for replacing Drive scopes. Check if you can get rid of this error by changing the scopes.

Comment: @KRR No, it doesn't affect it and gives back the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it. Somehow that error was raised by DataStoryFactory object in the following segment of code:

```
GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
                        HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, SCOPES)
                        .setDataStoreFactory(DATA_STORE_FACTORY)
                        .setAccessType("offline")
                        .build();
```

FileDataStoreFactory object was using "StoredCredential" file placed in the following directory:

```
$HOME/.credentials
```

So, all I needed to do is to delete that directory that it could create it again. After what it's gonna make a callback and ask you to grant permissions for your application in Google Console and now it's gonna work properly. Or you could just change userId in the following method:

```
Credential mCredential = new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, new LocalServerReceiver())
                        .authorize("user");
```